# PHP better login validation for PDO

Tags: php, pdo

My code works perfectly until the validation, When i enter wrong username it doesn't show Invaild `Username or Password!` but if i entered correct username but wrong password the message appears, How do i fix that?

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $username = $row['username'];
            $hash_password = $row['password'];

            if(password_verify($password, $hash_password)){
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            } else {
            die("Invaild Username or Password!");
        }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "An error occurred " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: the proper code, just for reference, [Authenticating a user using PDO and password_verify()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/password_hash)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oh, Thank you, That better.

Comment: your problem here is while operator

Comment: @YourCommonSense was just going to ask you about that, What is wrong about it exactly?

Comment: @YourCommonSense just figure it out, Thank you.

Comment: that's obvious. when no username found, we never enter in the while loop either, so all verifications are just bypassed. you just souldn't use while everywhere. this is called "cargo cult programming" when you are using a function just because it was used somewhere else. you should use functions on purpose only. while should be used only if multiple results are expected. otherwise fetch your row explicitly, without any loops

Comment: @CaliburVictorious is this fixed?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Yes, Just trying to see if i can recall sessions now.

Comment: ok, you haven't started any session according to the code you provided

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile session is start at my header But i didn't include it, But i just fixed the entire problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];

     try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $res = $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
        if (!$res){
           die("Invaild Username!");
        }

       while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
          $user_id = $row['user_id'];
          $username = $row['username'];
          $hash_password = $row['password'];

          if(password_verify($password, $hash_password)){
               $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
               $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
          } else {
              die("Invaild Username or Password!");
          }
     }
  } catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "An error occurred " . $e->getMessage();
 }
```

}

Comment: It won't work. It works not the way you think it does.